# Unable to upload file to a ie browser

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is supposed to

- login to a website,
- navigate through several screens,
- click a browse button,
- select a file, and
- upload it to the website.

I've gotten as far as clicking the browse button, but **I can't seem to figure out how to enter a path in the "Choose File to Upload" dialog and click the open button.**

Comment: Hi, please attach your code so that we can see your attempt.

Comment: Formatted text to improve readibility

Comment: Are you doing this all in pure powershell? I would personally recommend looking into how the actual request is made and just mimicking the request in powershell straight away. Alternatively, if the text box lets you auto enter, you might be able to manipulate the clipboard and copy/paste an address into it.